# NLTK - Decoding Unicode in custom corpus

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I have created a custom corpus using nltk's `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`.

There are unicode characters within the .txt files of my corpus which I'm unable to decode. I assume it's the fact this is a "plaintext" reader but need to decode this nonetheless.

Code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
import os



mr = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('C:\mycorpus', r'(?!\.).*\.txt',
        cat_pattern=os.path.join(r'(neg|pos)', '.*',))

for w in mr.words():
    print(w)
```

This will print the words of files that do not contain unicode in tokenized format, and then throws the following error:

```
for w in mr.words():
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 402, in iterate_from
    for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 296, in iterate_from
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 122, in _read_word_block
    words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1168, in readline
    new_chars = self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1400, in _read
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1431, in _incr_decode
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 30: invalid start byte
```

I have attempted to decode with:

```
mr.decode('unicode-escape')
```

which throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I am using Python 3.6.4.

Comment: You are attempting to decode a reader, which is not possible. Try decoding individual words `w.decode()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, trying to decode 'w' causes this error: 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Do you happen to know which word causes the problem?

Comment: Yes, "-" and "•" (bullet point) causes the problem. Other unicodes work fine such as the colon ":"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that NLTK's corpus reader assumes that your plain-text files were saved with UTF-8 encoding.
However, this assumption is apparently wrong, as the files were encoded with another codec.
My guess is that CP1252 (aka "Windows Latin-1") was used, because it's quite popular and it fits your description well: in that encoding, the em dash "–" is encoded with the byte `0x96`, which is mentioned in the error message.

You can specify the encoding of the input files in the constructor of the corpus reader:

```
mr = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(
    'C:\mycorpus',
    r'(?!\.).*\.txt',
    cat_pattern=os.path.join(r'(neg|pos)', '.*',),
    encoding='cp1252')
```

Try this, and check if the non-ASCII characters (em dash, bullet) are still correct in the output (and not replaced with mojibake).